# Changes in local folder not reflecting on git, openstack

Tags: git, gerrit, openstack

I am working on Openstack dev on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I fixed a small bug. The bug came back after a review for change. I made the change and pushed it to gerrit review. The problem now is, the small change is not getting uploaded in the remote review. After googling, I found that the folder which which had the file was present in the .gitignore. I removed that! The  problems still persists. It is there on local copy but the change is not present on the remote review copy. git log points the most recent commit. which has the change on the local copy, not the final copy.!

```
akoppad@akoppad:/opt/stack/horizon$ git status
# On branch bug/1189393
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   .gitignore
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   static/
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
akoppad@akoppad:/opt/stack/horizon$
```

After I upload the patch, the changes are still not present? I am not sure what is happening?

Here is the complete rundown of the entire process:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch bug/1189393
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   openstack_dashboard/static/dashboard/less/horizon.less
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       static/


akoppad@akoppad:/opt/stack/horizon$ git status
# On branch bug/1189393
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   openstack_dashboard/static/dashboard/less/horizon.less
#   new file:   static/dashboard/css/339f94897afb.css
#
akoppad@akoppad:/opt/stack/horizon$ 
git log 


commit 0a46d93a186ca32523d2d6166246c279eabf54b8
Author: Annapoornima Koppad <a.koppad@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Jul 6 12:07:23 2013 +0530

Added btn-create with btn-launch in loadbalancer dashboard

implements bug 1189393

Change-Id: Iceab75c34175677776107356435b421b54798e37

commit f2c7db09791dc8c4fb329f535c330bfd3bdf98f4
Author: Annapoornima Koppad <a.koppad@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jun 24 18:11:08 2013 +0530

Added btn-create loadbalancer dashboard

Fixes bug 1189393

Change-Id: Iceab75c34175677776107356435b421b54798e37

akoppad@akoppad:/opt/stack/horizon$ git commit -a
[bug/1189393 1e69613] There is an error with my git. The local changes are not reflecting on the review button. Please ignore if the changes that were asked are still not present on this commit.
 2 files changed, 5653 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
 create mode 100644 static/dashboard/css/339f94897afb.css
```

Appreciate any inputs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I found that the folder which which had the file was present in the .gitignore. I removed that! The problems still persists.

Removing that form the .gitignore isn't enough.

You need to add and commit the folder or files that were declared as ignored in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I added and committed the particular file as well. That particular file showed on git status as modified, and I added it to commit. However, the commit is still not showing up.

Comment: @Anuk did you push that commit?

Comment: I am following this gerrit workflow. It does not ask me to push the commit anywhere. https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/GerritWorkflow. Please help, I am stuck with this problem for quite sometime now. I added some more code to make myself clear.

Comment: @Anuk after the `git status`, did you do a git commit? (in order to commit the file in the `static` directory, that was previously ignored)

Answer (score 1):

The problem lay with the fact that once I updated the second set of review comments, there were two commits on my bug branch. After committing the second set of changes, Now, I had to do a rebase,

```
git rebase -i HEAD^2
```

Within this message, the two commits that were made appear, you have to squash the older commit. After doing this, I had to amend my commit using

```
git commit --amend
```

And then push it for review using,

```
git review
```

This would update the recent changes.

Comment: More detailed than in my answer. +1